# Can't rollback my own edit with > 2K reputation

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I have more than 2K rep, did some code cleanup on an answer, then realized I wasn't happy with the answer for other reasons. Want to rollback changes I made until I can investigate further.

For my revision I see:

```
Source | Edit | Link
```

For the previous revision (not by me) I see

```
Source | Edit | Rollback | Link
```

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43519092/revisions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "rollback" link is on the **target** revision, not on the one you want to "undo".

It would read as "rollback to *this* revision".

The UI you show means you can rollback your edit perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, was my bad. Sorry. As you suggested I rollbacked to previous revision and it worked.